# Connecting C# UdpClient to proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, udp, udpclient

I wanted to add a proxy layer to my C# app which connects to an ip address. I have my proxy server address and port but I don't know how I could use it with my UdpClient requests. Here is the code, thanks for any help.

```
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("IP Address", Port);
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
string ipaddr = IPText.Text;
try
{
    client.Connect(ipaddr, 80);
    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataText.Text);
    client.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
    client.AllowNatTraversal(true);
    client.DontFragment = true;
}
```

Comment: You can’t. Web proxies don’t do UDP.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer not UDP.  Also TLS/SSL is done over TCP nor UDP.